# Fetching an XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Below is the XML structure that I am using to pick the nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saw-sql="urn:saw-sql" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
    <xsd:complexType name="Row">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Column0" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="date" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;Financial Calendar&quot;.&quot;Date&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Financial Calendar&quot;.&quot;Date&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Financial Calendar" saw-sql:columnHeading="Daily" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="c1f8d3c16da4d2766" />
        <xsd:element name="Column1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="char" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;Customer Details&quot;.&quot;Customer Title&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Details&quot;.&quot;Customer Title&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Details" saw-sql:columnHeading="Channel" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="c7e5b7e356cc63ae3" />
        <xsd:element name="Column2" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="double" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;F&amp;R Sales, Balances, Exposures and Limits&quot;.&quot;Balances - Spot&quot;.&quot;Closing Balance&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Balances - Spot&quot;.&quot;Closing Balance&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="dimAggr" saw-sql:aggregationType="agg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Balances - Spot" saw-sql:columnHeading="Closing Balance" saw-sql:isDoubleColumn="false" saw-sql:columnID="c5d3ad4e6d8e6cc66" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-08-30</Column0>
        <Column1>Acquire</Column1>
        <Column2>182629341.8</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-08-30</Column0>
        <Column1>Cross-sell</Column1>
        <Column2>139272587.24</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-08-30</Column0>
        <Column1>Deepen</Column1>
        <Column2>182862985.56</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-08-31</Column0>
        <Column1>Acquire</Column1>
        <Column2>182629341.8</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-08-31</Column0>
        <Column1>Cross-sell</Column1>
        <Column2>139272587.24</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-08-31</Column0>
        <Column1>Deepen</Column1>
        <Column2>182862985.56</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-09-01</Column0>
        <Column1>Acquire</Column1>
        <Column2>182742974.13</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-09-01</Column0>
        <Column1>Cross-sell</Column1>
        <Column2>139423172.28</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-09-01</Column0>
        <Column1>Deepen</Column1>
        <Column2>183136223.84</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-09-02</Column0>
        <Column1>Acquire</Column1>
        <Column2>177144002.21</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-09-02</Column0>
        <Column1>Cross-sell</Column1>
        <Column2>134426394.95</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-09-02</Column0>
        <Column1>Deepen</Column1>
        <Column2>182969892.02</Column2>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>2013-09-03</Column0>
        <Column1>Acquire</Column1>
        <Column2>177120781.08</Column2>
      </Row>
              </rowSet>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is pick all the elements under "Row", in my case being "Column0","Column1" and "Column2".

Below is the code that I am using to fetch the results. Somehow, it aint working. Any help would be helpful.

```
private static IEnumerable GenerateDataSet(XDocument xmlDoc)
{
    XNamespace ns = @"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset";
    IEnumerable resultSet = (from result in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Row")
                             select new
                             {
                                 Date = DateTime.Parse(result.Element("Column0").Value),
                                 KPI = (result.Attribute("Column1").Value),
                                 Value = int.Parse(result.Attribute("Column2").Value)
                             });
    return resultSet;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. XML is case-sensitive, so you have to exactly match element name to make it work. `ROW` and `row` are two different elements.
2. `Columns1` and `Column2` are elements, not attributes.
3. You have to use namespace for `Column0`/`Column1`/`Column2` as well.
4. Use explicit cast to `DateTime`/`string`/`int` instead of `Value` property + `Parse` method calls. It's just better.

**Update**

1. `Column2` contains `decimal`/`double` value, not `int`s:

   ```
   XNamespace ns = @"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset";
   IEnumerable resultSet = (from result in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "ROW")
                            select new
                            {
                                Date = (DateTime)result.Element(ns + "Column0")),
                                KPI = (string)result.Element(ns + "Column1")),
                                Value = (decimal)result.Element(ns + "Column2"))
                            });
   ```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help. When I try the code. I get the below error
Message = "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: element"

Comment: @Navyseal Try it again, I've missed one `ns + `.

Comment: Hmm, when I try with the added namespace. I get a "base {System.SystemException} = {"Input string was not in a correct format."}" error.

Answer (score 2):

**ROW** and **Row** are not the same. Xml is *case-sensitive*. You need to use Row with lower-case because that is your element's name.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm using this code:

```
returnValue = (from rows in doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Row")
select (from columns in rows.Elements() select object)columns.Value).ToArray()
).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little?